# bash profile works for user but not sudo

Tags: bash

I've modified my .profile to include a folder if a flash drive is plugged in. When running the command as the user it works fine but tells me the scrip must be run by sudo (this is what i want). However, when i try to run it with sudo i get "command not found"

I have a symlink (flash) in my /var/www folder pointing to my /media/flash drive. (nevermind this setup since is just for dev)

this is my user's .profile :

```
# set PATH so it includes flash scripts
if [ -d "/var/www/flash/scripts" ] ; then
    PATH="/var/www/flash/scripts:$PATH"
fi
```

when trying to run as sudo i get:

```
sudo: script: command not found
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

When you run the script as `sudo` you are trying to access root. So your `$HOME/.profile` wont be accessed instead `/root/.profile` will be accessed.

So make the changes what ever you did in `$HOME/.profile` to `/root/.profile`. To create `/root/.profile`. Use the following commands.

```
sudo su
cd /root
touch .profile
```

after making the changes try running the script.

or edit `$HOME/.bashrc` and add the following line

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH $@'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried "alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH $@'" but i get "env: wp: Permission denied"

Comment: sorry, "wp" is the script

Comment: Try the other step I mentioned.

Comment: Read it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why) you should use `sudo su -p`

Answer (score 3):

that is the behavior of sudo in ubuntu..

for example run following command

```
echo 'echo $PATH' | sh
```

and than this one

```
echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo sh
```

you see the output is different!
to avoid different paths put the following in your ~/.bashrc

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

Comment: After putting alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH' into my .bashrc i get "env: wp: Permission denied"

Answer (score 3):

You can preserve the value of `$PATH` when using `sudo`. Use `visudo` to add `$PATH` to the list of variables to keep. A line like the following in `/etc/sudoers` should do the trick:

```
Defaults env_keep += "PATH"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also move your file in a sudoers used directory :

```
    sudo mv $HOME/bash/script.sh /usr/sbin/
```